# Weird namespace behaviour

Tags: python

When trying to run the following code:

```
i = 0
def truc():
    print (i)
    if (False): i = 0
truc()
```

it yields an UnboundLocalError, but

```
i = 0
def truc():
    print (i)
    #if (False): i = 0
truc()
```

doesn't.

Is that a wanted behaviour ?

Is there a way to modify the value of a variable without creating a new one ? I could use a dict of one element. It works but it seems ugly:

```
i = {0 : 0}
def truc():
    print (i[0])
    if (False): i[0] = 0
truc()
```

Isn't it a better solution ?

Comment: Bad but quick way: add `global i` to the function. Good way that takes a few more characters: don't change global variables from within a function, instead pass it in as a parameter and return the new value, calling it with `i = truc(i)`. Much more controllable in the long run.

Comment: return the new value and set the variable equal to the return value, you could also use a class and make it an attribute, just avoid using global.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
global i
```

at the beginning of the method `truc()` to declare that `i` is global variable

```
def truc():
    global i
    if (False):
        i = 0
```

Take a look at this [topic in Python's FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) to get more informations

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
def truc():
    global i
    print (i)
    if (False): i = 0
truc()
```

To refer the outer scope variable of the function, `i` should be declared as global.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to add `global i` to the function.

```
i = 0
def truc():
    global i
    if (False):
        i = 0
```

Other ways to handle this problem is:

Making `i` capitalized you'll be able to access it without the `global`        however `i` is then unchangeable which seems like something that isn't appropriate in your case.

Taking `i` as an argument. This makes the code less messy and easier to debug later.